# Disable swipe while using in stack navigator 4.0

Tags: reactjs, react-native

when stack navigator used in tab navigator while using stack navigator screen if swipe left then go to tab navigator next screen. I want to disable swipe while using stack navigator

Answer (score 0):

We can set the **gestureEnabled** property to false in the stack navigator at the time of the navigator creation in the navigationOptions or defaultNavigationOptions of the stack navigator.

as like:

```
gestureEnabled: true,
```

Check out the **official docs** for more information.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator/